# In welcher Bedeutung wird in »betont etwa eine Sprecherin« das Wort »etwa« verwendet?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

Ich habe diesen Satz in einem Artikel gelesen, der in einer Zeitung steht.

> “Wir sprechen nicht über unsere Vorkehrungen zum Schutz der Sicherheit unserer Passagiere und Mitarbeitenden”, betont etwa eine Sprecherin von American Airlines.

Wieso wurde hier *etwa* benutzt? 
Ich dachte, es bedeutet *about* oder *more or less.* 
Deshalb wirkt es auf mich so, als ob die Sprecherin herabgesetzt werden sollte, aber das kann sicherlich nicht der Fall sein.

Welche Bedeutung hat das Wort stattdessen?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... ich fand die Überschrift vorher besser. Ist es wirklich nötig, das Beispiel da reinzuschreiben? Wäre nicht "merkwürdige Verwendung von etwa" besser in den Suchergebnissen, wenn jemand eben nach einer Bedeutung für so ein "etwa" sucht? Gibt's da SE-Richtlinien? Und wozu bruacht man bei der Überschrift noch den Textbody?

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich alles andere als ein Experte für Suchmaschinenoptimierung, aber ich finde generell Suchergebnisse ansprechender, die mir so gut wie möglich mitteilen, was mich auf der entsprechenden Seite erwartet.  »merkwürdige Verwendung von etwa« kann ziemlich viel erfassen. Dass die Überschrift den kompletten Text vorwegnimmt, sehe ich hier nicht als gegeben und spricht wenn überhaupt eher gegen die Frage als die Überschrift.

Comment: Immerhin ist jetzt die Grammatik in der Überschrift richtig. Aber wieso beginnt sie mit einem kleinen Buchstaben?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft... ist definitiv Geschmacksache. Ich finde Überschriften voller Interpunktionszeichen nicht so schön, besonders, wenn sie direkt am Anfang stehen. Eine so spezifische Überschrift könnte auch jemanden, der im Grunde die selbe Frage hat, absckrechen, da sein Beispiel anders ist (z.B. "sagte etwa der Mann") aber auch das ist wohl Ansichtssache. Ich wollt's einfach mal erwähnen, da mir der Edit echt missfallen hat.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz... ja, das sind die Sachen, die dann passieren :) Es muss klein beginnen, da es ein Zitat ist, dass nicht mit "betont" beginnt. Wenn man es groß schreibt, könnte zudem die Frage auch um folgenden Satz gehen "Betont etwa die Sprecherin die Verantwortung?!" mit "etwa" im Sinne von "actually". So präzise ist das Snippet dann nicht mehr.

Comment: fixed :) Ich wollte zuerst "Sinn" statt "Bedeutung" schreiben, konnte mich dann aber nicht für oder gegen das Dativ-e entscheiden ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In diesem Kontext bedeutet *etwa* so viel wie [*beispielsweise, zum Beispiel*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/etwa_circa_beispielsweise#Bedeutung2).

Der Artikel kann [hier](http://www.aerotelegraph.com/wenn-fluglinien-passagiere-lebenslang-sperren-schwarze-liste-black-list) nachgelesen werden. Der Satz vor deinem Satz lautet

> Viel konkreter werden Fluggesellschaften allgemein nicht, wenn man sie auf ihre Sperr-Politik anspricht.

Der Autor sagt also, dass Fluggesellschaften Teile ihrer Sicherheitsvorschriften nicht offenbaren wollen. Um diese These zu untermauern, führt er als Beispiel das Zitat der American-Airlines-Sprecherin an.

Answer (score 4):

Das Wort heißt hier in etwa

> zum Beispiel

Answer (score 2):

Vom Fragesteller gestelltem Zertifikat "etwa" kann drei Bedeutungen annehmen:

> - ungefähr
> - beispielsweise, zum Beispiel
> - (schweizerisch) bisweilen,
>     manchmal

In dem genannten Zusammenhang kann "etwa" mit "beispielsweise" substituiert werden.

Comment: oder auch *"unter anderem"*